# Nested objects in json schema with "oneOf"

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json with nested structure and items may differ in each case.
So i decided to create schema like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "number"
          },
          {
            "type": "array"
          },
          {
            "type": "null"
          },
          {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "type": "number"
                },
                {
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to validate JSON:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": "somestring",
    "c": 12345,
    "arr": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "o": {
      "s": "somestring",
      "n": 12345
    }
  }
}
```

But every time i try to validate my json, i get error at field "o":

*JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'*

*Invalid type. Expected Boolean but got Object*

*Invalid type. Expected Null but got Object*

*Invalid type. Expected Array but got Object*

*Invalid type. Expected String but got Object*

*Invalid type. Expected Number but got Object*

Is it not allowed to use nested objects with "oneOf"?
Or maybe there is another solution for

Comment: This looks fine to me. What implementation are you using? Is that really your schema and instance? This playground uses draft-07, but it's the same for the schema you've given: https://jsonschema.dev/s/F4gRG

Comment: @Relequestual i use draft-04
This is just example, because i can`t show real schema

Comment: I can’t reproduce your error. Can you reproduce the error with your example Schema and data?

Comment: @Relequestual thx for help, i found my mistake in schema. It is possible to use nested "oneOf" as many time as you want

Comment: Given that you won't be updating your question to be reproducible, I suggest you delete. With JSON Schema, it's important to recognise what values are subschemas. Subschemas are schemas in their own right.